# Silverlight doesn't play mp3

Tags: silverlight, mp3

I am using VS2010,C# to develop a Silverlight web based game. I want to play mp3 and this is my existing code:

```
StreamResourceInfo sri = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("/TennisSL;component/Images/idle.mp3", UriKind.Absolute));
m.SetSource(sri.Stream);
Scene.Children.Add(m);
m.Play(); // Plays the sound
```

The above code does not play as no sound is heard! What could be wrong? Is there anything missing?

This is my MediaElement object declaration at the top of program:

```
MediaElement m = new MediaElement();
```

Comment: Silverlight seems to be able to support MP3s, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189080%28v=vs.95%29.aspx. Try adding an event handler to the MediaElement's `MediaFailed` event.  If this event handler gets called, what's the exception in the `ExceptionRoutedEventArgs` parameter?

Comment: thanks, I test it, I've also used MediaElement tag in my XAML, but there is still no luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following code :

m.Position = new TimeSpan(0,0,0);

then :

m.Play();

Thay way, you put the stream back to the start position and you can play the sound.